# Can I have a case class with default/hardcoded values

Tags: scala, adt

For example say I have a sealed trait AnimalSoundsand I have case class "Dog" and a case class "Cat"
I want the two case classes value to default to "Woof" and "Cat"

```
sealed trait AnimalSounds extends Product with Serializable
final case class Dog(sound: String = "woof") extends AnimalSounds
final case class Cat(sound: String = "meow") extends AnimalSounds

println(Dog.sound)
```

I get the error "sound is not a member of object"

Comment: I would suggest that you read the basis first of how to access members of a case class!

Comment: If you want that sound to behave like a constant that nobody could change and that is available without creating an instance, create it on the **Companion object** instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "hardcoded" it is meant constants consider `case objects` like so

```
sealed trait AnimalSounds { val sound: String }
case object Dog extends AnimalSounds { val sound = "woof" }
case object Cat extends AnimalSounds { val sound = "meow" }

Dog.sound
```

which outputs

```
res0: String = woof
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with a case class *instance*, you first need to create one:

```
val d: Dog = Dog()
println(d.sound)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided the defaults in your case class, you can also so

```
Dog().sound
```